# How to Customize Build and Publish Process

Tags: .net, asp.net, svn, design-patterns, msbuild

I have a Website with these properties

- .NET 3.5
- Asp.NET 2.0
- Use Local Resources to control TEXT of elements
- SVN // for source Control
- Publish with Visual Studio

Then I have some sub Directories which categorized website into different parts.

Now I have another customer that need some `customization` in Main Website. for example:

- Changes belongs to 1 or 2 Sub Directories out of 15
- Change some Text
- Remove some pages, because he doesn't need them
- Some new Pages
- Some new fields in some pages
- Some minor changes

With all these background, What's the best practice to publish this website?

These are my ideas

1. Create New subdirectories with new name and copy all pages in this one. then apply all changes in this. >>>> this would be the last option
2. Create seperate SubDirectories and copy the necessary one inot main Solution Just for publish and keep the main subdirectory in website. >>>> I'm not sure that this would be a good idea because we publish once a week
3. Create a new Website for directories which should be changed and then publish them seperately, then merge the result with Main website >>> actually I don't know How to do this and also I'm not sure that it will work or not

Could you please give me some solution. Just consider that I have to publish once a week (because of the SLA) so that I need minimum changes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy).

It would take an investment to setup, but you could create a single package of your site with [parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338472%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).  Then when publishing you would replace the necessary parameters and use [skip and replace rules](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2008/05/23/how-to-write-skip-and-replace-rules-for-msdeploy.aspx) to skip or replace customer specific files.  The best part is that this could would be automated making your deployment process easy since you'll be doing it often.

Comment: as I understand Web Deploy is a synchronization tool between 2 IIS in source and destination. I couln't understand that how can it help me to publish my website? could you please explain more? in the second article which was about MSBuild there was some configuration to customize build process but again I couln't understand that what was the relation between this and Web Deploy.  I'm waiting to hear from you

Comment: Just Note that I'm using Visual Studio to publish my website. So give me a how to publish Guid please

Comment: Well I missed the Publish with Visual Studio, but you may have to get out of your comfort zone here a bit.  Any project in Visual Studio 2008 and above is an MSBuild project and you can edit that project to add additional functionality, such as using Web Deploy.  The basic process would be to create a target in the .csproj file and add MSDeploy functionality.  You'd then call this via the command line.  `msbuild <project.proj> /t:<yourTarget>`.